# Proving a Ring is commutative if every element is idempotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I had this question on a final exam.  I was wondering if anyone knows a proof for it.

Let R be a ring not necessarily with unity ($1 \neq 0$ and $x \in R$ so that $x*1=x=1*x$) and let R have the property that every element of R is idempotent that is $\forall x \in R\quad x*x=x$.  Prove that $R$ is commutative.

Not to put my whole answer up because I know I was wrong.  I will put the part where I had trouble going to the next step.

My argument went like this:  let $a,b \in R$ then $ab\in R$ cause $R$ is a ring.  Therefore $abab=ab$.

Now $aabb=ab$ as well, so $$abab=aabb\ \Rightarrow abab-aabb=0 \Rightarrow\ a(ba-ab)b=0\ \because\text{ distributive property of $R$}.$$

Now because R is not a division ring then the element $a$ could be a divisor of zero or $b$ could be as well so you cannot just assume $ba-ab=0$.  This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 16):

Note that $(x+y)=(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2$. Now, using the property that $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$, we have $xy+yx=0$ so that $xy=-(yx)$. Also, since $x=x^2=(-x)^2=-x$, each element is its own additive inverse, i.e., $xy=yx$ so the ring is commutative.

Comment: So (as shown above by Clayton) $x+x=0$ for any $x\in R$.

Comment: @Clayton thanks for the help it kind of makes me angry that I missed the question on the test considering the answer is so simple :).

Comment: @drew, no problem! I'm glad you understand it; that is key.

Comment: Dude, the OP said the ring does not necessarily have unity, so '$x=x^2=(−x)^2=−x$' does not work. For a correct approach, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring#:~:text=Every%20Boolean%20ring%20R%20satisfies%20x%20%E2%8A%95%20x%20%3D%200%20for%20all%20x%20in%20R%2C%20because%20we%20know).

Comment: @Michael try reading your link. A proof that a Boolean ring is commutative is given that matches my proof exactly. It has nothing to do with unity.

Comment: Without unity, how do you prove '$x^2=(−x)^2$'?